# No me funciona menu hamburguesa, no despliega

Tags: html, css, scss

Tengo un problema con una web y no sé por que no se despliega el menú hamburguesa. Supongo que falta algo de código. cuando aprieto el checkbox y no despliega el menú, no se como hacer que funcione, necesito una corrección o explicación, tiene SCSS

```html
    <nav class="index-nav">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
            <label for="check" class="hamburger-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li class="nav-list__item"><a class="nav-list__txt active" href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
            <li class="nav-list__item"><a class="nav-list__txt" href="pages/quienessomo.html">Quienes Somos</a></li>
            <li class="nav-list__item"><a class="nav-list__txt" href="pages/resena.html">Reseña Historica</a></li>
            <li class="nav-list__item"><a class="nav-list__txt" href="pages/ideario.html">Ideario</a></li>
            <li class="nav-list__item"><a href="pages/oferta.html">Oferta Academica</a></li>
            <li class="nav-list__item"><a href="pages/contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Necesito una correcion

```css
    .index-nav {
    .menu-btn {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #531919;
        height: 52px;
        .hamburger-btn {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            align-items: center;
        }
        #check {
            display: visible;
            &:checked ~ .nav-list {
                background: green;
                min-height: 100vh;
                li {
                    visibility: visible;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .nav-list {
        background-color: $almostgray;
        font-size: 2rem;
        padding: 8px 0px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .nav-list__item {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 10px;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
    a {
        color: $lightgray;
        &:hover {
            color: $lightred;
            padding-bottom: 8px;
        }
    }
    .nav-list .nav-list__item:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No hagas eso. Utilizar texto como AAA para rellenar porque no llegas al mínimo de caracteres de explicación es una mala praxis que deberías evitar, sobre todo si quieres que tu pregunta se tome en serio, deberías reformular tu pregunta y dar mas detalles. ¿Estás usando bootstrap? ¿Como has hecho la hamburguesa, mediante scss? ¿Trabajando con viewports? ¿O es Javascript?  Mirando tu código puedo ver que es normal que no funcione, nada de lo que has incluido haría que funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que buscas algo como esto:

```css
.nav-list {
  display: none;
  background-color: $almostgray;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hamburger-btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#check {
  display: none
}

#check:checked~.nav-list {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-list>li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

a {
  color: lightgray;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="index-nav">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <label for="check" class="hamburger-btn">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-list" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
</svg>
        </label>
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-list__item"><a class="nav-list__txt active" href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
    <li class="nav-list__item"><a class="nav-list__txt" href="pages/quienessomo.html">Quienes Somos</a></li>
    <li class="nav-list__item"><a class="nav-list__txt" href="pages/resena.html">Reseña Historica</a></li>
    <li class="nav-list__item"><a class="nav-list__txt" href="pages/ideario.html">Ideario</a></li>
    <li class="nav-list__item"><a href="pages/oferta.html">Oferta Academica</a></li>
    <li class="nav-list__item"><a href="pages/contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Lo importante esta aqui:

```
.nav-list {
  display: none;
}

#check {
  display: none
}

#check:checked~.nav-list {
  display: block;
}
```

El selector `~` toma el elemento `nav-list` hermano (del mismo padre) del checkbox. Al hacer click y checkearlo, con `display: block` los vuelve visibles.

Comment: Tenes discord? y te mando mensaje privado